# How to change content of a given paragraph based on the width of viewport (i.e dynamic content replacement)

Tags: jquery, html

How can I change the content of a given paragraph when the browser width is resized? For example, on mobile version of my website I would like the paragraph with class '.main-lead' to have the following content:

```
<p class="main-lead">Some content goes here.</br>And some content goes here</p>
```

Now, when someone views this page from tablet or laptop, I would like the content of this paragraph to be changed like so:

```
<p class="main-lead">Previous content has been replaced.</p>
```

I sort of understand that I need to do it using jQuery, and I have attempted to write a script to do this task:

```
jQuery(window).resize(function () {
    if ($(window).width() > 768) {
        // if screen width is more than 768px
        $(".main-lead").html('Previous content has been replaced.');
    }
});
```

It seems to work, however if the user decides to resize the screen back to mobile view, the content will remain the same as on the tablet and desktop version instead of mobile version.

Thus, I would like the content of this paragraph to dynamically change when the browser window is being resized back and forth.

Any suggestions will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also try with css code.

```
<style>
.mobile { display:none; }
@media screen and (max-width:768px) { 
.desktop { display:none; }
.mobile { display:block; }
 } 
</style>
<p class="main-lead">
    <span class="desktop">Some content goes here.</br>And some content goes here</span>
    <span class="mobile">Previous content has been replaced.</span>
</p>
```

Comment: I think this is preferable to a js solution whenever possible

Comment: Ah, why haven't I thought about using this idea with Bootstraps hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md etc classes. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Fine, if you are using bootstrap framework its a better idea.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var $window = $(window),
  $mainLead = $(".main-lead"); // cacheing the main elements for reuse

$window.resize(function() {
  if ($window.width() > 768) {
    // if screen width is more than 768px
    $mainLead.html($mainLead.data('contentNotMobile'));
  } else {
    // if screen width is NOT more than 768px
    $mainLead.html($mainLead.data('contentMobile'));
  }
});

$window.trigger('resize'); // fire the resize even on load to catch the initial state of the page
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="main-lead" data-content-mobile="Some content goes here.</br>And some content goes here" data-content-not-mobile="Previous content has been replaced.">Some content goes here.</br>And some content goes here</p>
```

You'll need to cache (store as a variable, data attribute, et cetera) the "original" content before making the switch. In the my example, I'm storing both versions of the content as HTML `data-attributes` to avoid having to manage the initial content of the `<p>`. Note that you will have to "catch" the initial state of your page, too. That is done with the `$window.trigger('resize')` after the listener has been set up.

Then, it is as simple as extending your existing `if` block with an `else` that fires whenever the `$(window).width()` is NOT greater than `768`, and restores the cached content/string. [jQuery's `.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/) is a convenient way to store such information, though there are a number of other ways you could do it.